# Partially translated dashboard in one of network's site

Tags: multisite, translation

I have multisite WordPress installation with default language for all new sites set to English. For one of my sites I wanted to add support for different (Polish) language. I copied all Polish *.mo files I found in Polish installation of WordPress.

After switching to that language that one site only, I noticed that not only frontend, but also dashboard has been translated into Polish. Because that was unwanted effect, I deleted all *.mo files from languages directory, except for pl_PL.mo. Especially I removed *.mo files for admin and network admin.

Even though I did it, I can see right now, that my Dashboard for this site is partially translated into Polish. Only certain strings (dashboard sections, frames, buttons) are translated, other remains in English.

What is going on? Form where this partial translation comes out? I only left pl_PL.mo file, which (as I understand) purely for frontend translation and does not changes anything it dashboard.

This case goes for my test blog (network's site), so I can use ultimate solution -- that is, delete whole site and re-create it again. But even though, I'm pretty curious, what has happened, and what to do, if similar problem appear in the future for one of my production blogs?

Comment: *Since I only use pl_PL.mo file and not admin or network related files, there should be no translation of dashboard at all. Only frontend should be (and was) translated. And there was no translation of dashboard before, when I first time used only pl_PL.mo file. Then I added others (admin-network-pl_PL.mo and admin-pl_PL.mo), but when removed them again, translation of dashboard remained. It looks like Wordpress has remembered some translation and not cleared it up, back to default English language. If such situation is possible at all.*

Comment: The previous is a comment @trejder left to an Answer I provided and may be useful to understand the issue. But it was a bad interpretation of the Question on my part, so just deleted it. (trejder, as now you can't delete your comment, ping me if you want the previous removed).

Comment: No, it is fine with me. BTW: After another take a look, I think that a partial translation of a dashboard could simply be part of `pl_PL.mo` file. After all -- no one said, that this file contains only frontend translation, right? That was my assumption and this can be wrong.

Comment: I don't have a fine understanding of how this works, but at first, as far as I know, front end translations are mainly a matter of `/my-theme/language/my-theme.mo`... That's why I asked you to check the faulty strings within `/wp-content/languages/pl_PL.po`...